# Sql update doesn't work unless choosing a upload file

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

in this edit file i have to choose the same picture file or another picture file to be able update the rows. but i want to be able to change whichever i want without touching the other rows. any ideas over here?

```
<?php

include ("../header.php");
include ("../header2.php");

?>
<?php
include('../config.php');
include ('../ac.thumbs.php');

 if ($_GET['sil']) {
    $sil = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['sil']));

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM CloseOut WHERE itemNO = $sil limit 1");
    echo "<h1>$sil item nolu kayit silinmistir</h1><br>";
}

    $edit = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET['edit']));
    //Resimlerin yuklenecegin yer
 $target = "../../upload/";  
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ///////////////////////////////Resim1/////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']) ; 
 //Formdan gelen bilgileri almasi icin
 $resim=($_FILES['resim1']['name']); 
 $isim=$_POST['isim1']; 
 $alan1=$_POST['alan11']; 
 $alan2=$_POST['alan21']; 
 $alan3=$_POST['alan31']; 
 $alan4=$_POST['alan41']; 



/////////////Formdaki bos alanlara bos bilgi kayit etmemesi icin////////////////////////

$updates = array();
if (!empty($resim))
  $updates[] = 'resim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($resim).'"';
if (!empty($isim))
  $updates[] = 'isim="'.mysql_real_escape_string($isim).'"';
if (!empty($alan1))
  $updates[] = 'alan1="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan1).'"';
if (!empty($alan2))
  $updates[] = 'alan2="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan2).'"';
if (!empty($alan3))
  $updates[] = 'alan3="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan3).'"';
if (!empty($alan4))
  $updates[] = 'alan4="'.mysql_real_escape_string($alan4).'"';
$updates = implode(', ', $updates);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //update etmesi icin
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resim1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) 
{   
mysql_query("UPDATE CloseOut SET $updates WHERE itemNO='$edit' ");
echo "Tebrikler, ". basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']). " isimli dosya yuklendi ve database'e basariyla islendi!<br>"; 
 } 




 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CloseOut WHERE itemNO=$edit") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { echo "
<center>
<a href=\"edit.php?sil=$info[itemNO]\"onclick=\"return confirm('Do you really want to erase this entry?')\">[ Delete ]</a><br>
<a href=../../large.php?f=upload/".$info['resim'], $thumblarge .">
<img src=../../small.php?f=upload/".$info['resim'], $thumbsmall .">
</a>";
$editresim = $info[resim];
$editisim = $info[isim];
$editalan1 = $info[alan1];
$editalan2 = $info[alan2];
$editalan3 = $info[alan3];
$editalan4 = $info[alan4];
} 


?>

<br>
<center> 
<table width="900" border="5" style="background-color:white; "bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>RESIM</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>NAME</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>CATAGORY</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>QUANTITY</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>LOCATION</b></td>
        <td width="120" height="50" bgcolor= "545454"><b>PRICE</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<td><input type="file" name="resim1" value="<?php echo $editresim;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="isim1" value="<?php echo $editisim;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan11" value="<?php echo $editalan1;?>"> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan21" value="<?php echo $editalan2;?>">  </td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan31" value="<?php echo $editalan3;?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="alan41" value="<?php echo $editalan4;?>"></td>
</tr>

<td colspan="6"><center><input type="submit"></center></td>


</form>
</table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resim1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) 
{   
    mysql_query("UPDATE CloseOut SET $updates WHERE itemNO='$edit' ");
    echo "Tebrikler, ". basename( $_FILES['resim1']['name']). " isimli dosya yuklendi ve database'e basariyla islendi!<br>"; 
}
```

If you don't upload anything, then `move_uploaded_file` is going to return false and your update will never happen.

Comment: so i just need to figure out a code saying if there is no upload file then ignore move_uploaded_file?? would that resolve?

Comment: You need to run the query on update with or without an uploaded file.

Comment: im sorry im really on beginning stage im not understanding that fully.. can you be little specific if possible please.